# Lightweight java properties UI for business people

Tags: java, properties, soa, business-rules

Basically I have a composite service layer on top of backend services. The composite layer serves the fronts by simplifying queries etc... The idea has been to keep application logic out of the composite layer as much as possible. However, as usually is the case, for complicated (business) reasons I have to include some business rules to my service layer, E.g.:

```
minimum_subscription_length_for_product_X=5_days
```

What is the up-to-date way of letting the business people CRUD simple rules in a simple java application? I don't want to include a software engineer in the rule maintenance process but don't want to spend tons of money on fancy GUIs either. What is the up-to-date lightweight compromise?

Comment: How would you see Apache ISIS for this?

Answer (score 1):

What kind of UI do you need? In case of traditional desktop app, would an inspector be appropriate?

[image: Inspector]

More info about implementing one is in this question:

[Creating an inspector window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1767008/java-beans-creating-an-inspector-window)

Answer (score 1):

Most Rules Engines come with GUI's out of the box. How about using one such as JBoss Drools?